# How do i overwrite a field in a csv file with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, csv

CSV sample:

[image: CSV Sample]

I have the below code, where I would like to overwrite the current value in the PreviousGroup field. I know that `-append` adds to the end of the column, but that's not what I want to do.

```
$UserGroup = read-host "Enter Group Name"
$csvFile = Import-Csv "C:\HomeFolder\Locations.csv"
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($PreviousGroup)) {$PreviousGroup = ""}
else {$PreviousGroup = $csvFile | Select-Object $csvFile.PreviousGroup -Verbose}

$csvFile.PreviousGroup = $UserGroup
$csvFile | Export-Csv
```

Secondly, is it possible to link Dom*_Groups in the below code to the list on the CSV?

```
param([Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [ValidateSet(*"list from csv"*)] [string]$Dom1_Groups)
param([Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [ValidateSet(*"list from csv"*)] [string]$Dom2_Groups)
```

Comment: CSV is a simple text file, and if there is a specific string to replace, just search and replace that. This is a very common thing with [tons of search-replace samples all over the web](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+search+and+replace+csv+text%27&t=h_&ia=web) and in the Powershell help files.

Comment: As for the _Secondly_ part of your question: Please focus on a _single_ question at time.

Answer (score 1):

`$csvFile`, as returned from [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv), is an *array* of `[pscustomobject]` instances.

Therefore, *assigning* to the `.PreviousGroup` property of `$csvFile` in an attempt to assign to *its elements'* `.PreviousGroup` properties will *not* work: while it's understandable to attempt this, given that *getting* the elements' property values this way *does* work, via *member-access enumeration*, **[member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) by design only works for *getting*, [not also for *setting*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5271#issuecomment-340285892)  property values.**

The simplest solution is to **use the [`.ForEach()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach)**:

```sh
# Set the .PreviousGroup property of all elements of array $csvFile
# to the value of $UserGroup.
$csvFile.ForEach('PreviousGroup', $UserGroup)
```

**Caveat**: As of PowerShell 7.1, the above method of assigning property values unexpectedly *fails* if the input object happens to be a *scalar* (single object), which can happen if the CSV file happens to contain just *one* data row; see [GitHub issue #14527](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14527).
An - inefficient - workaround is to use `@()`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--):
`@($csvFile).ForEach('PreviousGroup', $UserGroup)`
or to use a *script block* (`{ ... }`):
`$csvFile.ForEach({ $_.PreviousGroup = $UserGroup })`

Comment: i guess I should consider using a text file, like 
`New-Item -path $PSScriptRoot -name PreviousGroup.txt -type "file" -Value $UserGroup` & `Set-Content $PSScriptRoot\PreviousGroup.txt -Value $UserGroup` at the end of my function.

Comment: @Nuisance, I thought you wanted to update _CSV_ data, not plain text. Does the solution in this answer not address the scenario in your question and, if not, why?

Comment: yes I wanted to use a single .CSV. I'm opting for the.txt solution because it is something I've done before on another script and only needs a few lines of code.